# Rails has_many multiple joins with record count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is it possible to join two tables and count both of their relationship count? the ideal output is 
`[name, recommendation_count, review_count]`

```
class PatientProfile
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :recommendations

# this works
PatientProfile.joins(:reviews).group(:id).pluck(:name, 'count(reviews.id)')

# this does not work
PatientProfile.joins(:recommendations, :reviews).group(:id).pluck(:name, 'count(recommendations.id)', 'count(reviews.id)')
```

The second example returns the value of `'count(recommendations.id)'` for both columns

Comment: Can you provide details about your models/relationship?

Comment: @archana added more info about models

Comment: where is your `has_many :through` relation?

Comment: @archana updated, that was incorrect. just a count on `has_many`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
PatientProfile
  .joins(:recommendations, :reviews)
  .group(:id)
  .pluck(:name,
         'count(distinct recommendations.id)',
         'count(distinct reviews.id)')
```

I'd strongly recommend to start learning SQL. ActiveRecord is not magic wand, but tool for building SQL queries. Moreover, ActiveRecord has its own restrictions. So SQL is base when using RDBMS in an application.

Also, it would be helpful to read about `counter_cache` [there](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). It will simplify and speed up any `count(...)` queries.

**Added**:

> how would you tweak it to include all PatientProfiles, not just those
>   with a recommendation count or review count?

`.joins` generates `LEFT INNER JOIN` SQL clause while now you need `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.
Rails 5+:

```
PatientProfile
  .left_joins(:recommendations, :reviews)
  # ...
```

Rails < 5 cheat:

```
PatientProfile
  .eager_load(:recommendations, :reviews)
  # ...
```

Comment: thanks. this is great. how would you tweak it to include all `PatientProfiles`, not just those with a recommendation count or review count?

Comment: `.joins` generates `LEFT INNER JOIN` SQL clause while now you need `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Rails 5+ has `.left_outer_joins` for this.